# center align ul inside div with display:table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centrally align the `ul li` text inside the `main div`. Exactly `text align center` the text. I don't want to do it with the `margin`. What is an elegant way?

> I need to keep the display table setup for vertical alignment.

MY HTML:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
Anchor
                </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Center this</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-div {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

CodePen is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLoVGR)

Comment: @dippas, my `display:table` makes the question unique

Comment: in the 1st answer/accepted one to that question it using `display: table` and there is still a few (at least) of this question even with `display: table` so  no not unique